# Add Combobox Items to Dynamically added controls

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a panel wherein I can add set of combobox and textbox. I want to add items to the dynamically added combobox from my database. How to add items to dynamically added combobox?

This is my code for dynamically adding combobox from a button click.

```
    Dim number As Integer = 2
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim itemCombobox As New ComboBox
    itemCombobox.Name = "itemCombobox" + number.ToString
    itemCombobox.Location = New Point(25, number * 29)
    itemCombobox.Size = New Point(113, 23)
    itemCombobox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList

    Dim qtyTxtbox As New MaskedTextBox
    qtyTxtbox.Name = "qtyTxtbox" + number.ToString
    qtyTxtbox.Location = New Point(172, number * 29)
    qtyTxtbox.Size = New Point(37, 20)

    Dim specsBtn As New ComboBox
    specsBtn.Name = "specsBtn" + number.ToString
    specsBtn.Location = New Point(236, number * 29)
    specsBtn.Size = New Point(113, 23)
    specsBtn.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList

    Dim bmCombobox As New ComboBox
    bmCombobox.Name = "bmCombobox" + number.ToString
    bmCombobox.Location = New Point(385, number * 29)
    bmCombobox.Size = New Point(113, 23)
    bmCombobox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList

    Panel8.Controls.Add(itemCombobox)
    Panel8.Controls.Add(qtyTxtbox)
    Panel8.Controls.Add(specsBtn)
    Panel8.Controls.Add(bmCombobox)
    number = number + 1

End Sub
```

This is my function to add items to the itemcombobox

```
Private Sub load_item1()
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;  username=root; password=p@ssw0rd; database= atos_db"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "select * from atos_db.item_tbl"
        comm = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            Dim sItem = reader.GetString("item")
            itemCombobox1.Items.Add(sItem)
        End While
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

How do i get the values for each dynamically added controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable "itemCombobox" is declared inside the methode  "Button1_Click" so he can't be used in your method "load_item1".
to do this you must declare your variable as global in your classe like :

```
      Dim itemCombobox As New ComboBox
     Dim number As Integer = 2
      Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        itemCombobox.Name = "itemCombobox" + number.ToString
        itemCombobox.Location = New Point(25, number * 29)
        itemCombobox.Size = New Point(113, 23)
        itemCombobox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList

        Dim qtyTxtbox As New MaskedTextBox
        qtyTxtbox.Name = "qtyTxtbox" + number.ToString
        qtyTxtbox.Location = New Point(172, number * 29)
        qtyTxtbox.Size = New Point(37, 20)

        Dim specsBtn As New ComboBox
        specsBtn.Name = "specsBtn" + number.ToString
        specsBtn.Location = New Point(236, number * 29)
        specsBtn.Size = New Point(113, 23)
        specsBtn.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList

        Dim bmCombobox As New ComboBox
        bmCombobox.Name = "bmCombobox" + number.ToString
        bmCombobox.Location = New Point(385, number * 29)
        bmCombobox.Size = New Point(113, 23)
        bmCombobox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList

        Panel8.Controls.Add(itemCombobox)
        Panel8.Controls.Add(qtyTxtbox)
        Panel8.Controls.Add(specsBtn)
        Panel8.Controls.Add(bmCombobox)
        number = number + 1

       Dim theButton As Button
       theButton = New Button
       theButton.Location = location
       theButton.Text = label
       AddHandler theButton.Click, AddressOf Me.btn_clicked

    End Sub
```

and use this variable in methode `load_item1()` :

```
Private Sub load_item1()
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;  username=root; password=p@ssw0rd; database= atos_db"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "select * from atos_db.item_tbl"
        comm = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            Dim sItem = reader.GetString("item")
            itemCombobox.Items.Add(sItem)
        End While
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btn_clicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim selectedBtn As Button = sender
    MsgBox("you have clicked button " & selectedBtn.Name)
End Sub
```

Comment: my problem is i want to do something like this
itemCombobox+number.toString.items.add(sItem)

so that I can add the list in the added controls also.

Comment: If you change your code as describe in my answer, you can addItem to  the dynamically added combobox

Comment: Im sorry, i'm still a student and I dont know much yet.
The output of the code will be something like this..
itemCombobox2, itemCombobox3, itemCombobox3 ....
bmCombobox2, bmCombobox2, bmCombobox3....
etc.

Comment: Ok i have edit my answer ttry to test it and tell me know

Comment: Omg, i think its okay now. i put the load_item function at the button click and it works fine now. Thank you sir. :)

Comment: i am glade to hear that, can you mark the answer please, thanks

Comment: can i ask another question? How do I add click event handler on the dynamically added button?

Comment: Yes of cours ,i have edit my answer to show you how to cretae a button and handler it with a event (Click for exemple)